# Чи може безособове дієслово відмінюватись як особове?

Tags: дієслова, дієвідмінювання

Відомо, що безособові дієслова не мають ні особи, ні роду, ні числа. Лише час: минулий, теперішній та майбутній. Проте нерідко трапляється, що безособове дієслово відмінюють за родами або особами. Наприклад, слово "світати" подеколи відмінюють так: світаю, світаєш, світаємо, світав, світай, світайте ...
Аналогічно зі словами "розвиднятися", "закортіти", "захотітися" та іншими.

Чи є таке відмінювання нормативним? Чи слово, що відмінюється подібним чином, є окремою лексичною одиницею, тобто не є безособовим? Також цікаво, чи мають безособові дієслова дієвідміну?

**Update**

Посилання на slovnyk.ua, де безособові слова відмінюються за особами: 
[світати](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8),
[розвиднятися](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F),
[закортіти](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8).

Натомість лише за часами ці ж слова відмінюються на  [lcorp.ulif](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) та [goroh](http://goroh.pp.ua/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: Re: *"слово "світати" подеколи відмінюють так"* — напевне, має сенс надати джерела, щоб було зрозуміло, хто і чому відмінює. Щоб нам не доводилося вгадувати. Бо це цілком може бути, наприклад, результатом друкарської помилки чи особистої неграмотності того, хто відмінює.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

З великою імовірністю, сайт `slovnyk.ua` **програмно створює** «відмінювані» форми цих дієслів, бо хтось не прописав движку, що ці слова не мають особових форм.
А насправді, таких форм не існує.

Пруф:

- [*розвидняєшся*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%94%D1%88%D1%81%D1%8F")
- [*світаєте*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%94%D1%82%D0%B5")
- [*закорчу*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q="%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D1%83") :-)

---

### Чтиво

- Слова, які не мають деяких (або усіх) форм відмінювання, називаються [неповними](http://jak.magey.com.ua/articles/bagati-i-nedostatni-dieslova-perevazhna-bilshist.html) або [дефектними](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb#Ukrainian).